# Android Trigger of Play Auto Install

Tags: android, google-play-services

Google created the functionality called PAI (Play AUto Install) on Android that automatically downloads apks from Play Store after factory reset if connected to network. What exactly trigger this functionality in android code. (I assume that the stub and the device config apk are correctly installed in the image).

Answer (score 0):

What exactly trigger this functionality in android code?

-> The presence of the PlayAutoInstallConfig.apk with APKversion:=1 in /system/app/PlayAutoInstallConfig/ on the device.